# Why does Visual Studio compile my HTTP server app to run on port 5001 when I set it to 443/80?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a separate place from launchsettings.json I need to set the applicationUrl?

Here's the launch setting

```
"applicationUrl": "https://127.0.0.1:443;http://127.0.0.1:80"
```

Here's a picture of the app when running inside Visual Studio
[image]

Here's a picture of it running from the compiled exe (release & debug)
[image]

Comment: Post your **entire** `launchSettings.json`. Also, are you using IIS Express or Kestrel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` used during development, for example, run from the visual studio or using `dotnet run` command.

If you want to configure the URL when run compiled exe, could add this:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://127.0.0.1:80"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://127.0.0.1:443"
      }
    }
  }
```

to the file `appsettings.json` or `Program.cs`.

Answer (score 2):

The config file `launchSettings.json` is only honored in a few places, such as

- Debug from Visual Studio
- `dotnet run`

So if you find it ignored, you know clearly that's by design and you should use other ways to configure Kestrel ports,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#url-prefixes

Answer (score 1):

You can also use config for Kubernetes

```
Kestrel__EndPoints__Http__Url : http://+:80
```